# android studio: place recycleview on top of Edittext with transparent background

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to implement a chat activity where the background of the EditText is transparent, so on scrolling up the messages are visible behind the Edittext. But this is the result :

[image]

As you can see it is not perfect, I want to be able to scroll a little more to make messages above the `edittext` completely not behind it!

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

        android:layout_below="@+id/bar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_send"
            android:background="@drawable/sendmessage"
            android:hint="Type a message ... "
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_paper_plane"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it all in a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_send"
            android:hint="Type a message ... "
            android:padding="8dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tied this, but it makes the edittext floating up and recycleview becomes unscrollable

Comment: @SSS I think I maybe made an issue in my answer. I changed wrap_content to match_parent. Please try my answer again.

Comment: I already tried to do this change. but when the messages are alot then the edittext goes out of the page and when there aren't many messages then the edittext is floating up and it goes down more with every new message. I wanted to be fixed at the bottom

Comment: I also made the recycleView android:layout_height="warp_content" instead of match_parent

Comment: @SSS Try to add android:layout_weight="1" to the recyclerview. (and use the LinearLayout)

Comment: yes now it is working but the background of the edittext is not transparent anymore, do you have any idea how to fix it? it shows a grey background but I want it transparent

Comment: @SSS I edited my answer and posted the full code. It should be transparent now.

Comment: still not transparent. still has a grey background

Comment: may I ask you a question? what have you added to this code besides android:background="@android:color/transparent" to make it transparent?

Comment: @SSS I didn't add the background. I just added the LinearLayout and the android:layout_weight="1". The code should be transparent without any special changes. When I change the background of LinearLayout to e.g. blue I can see the blue background behind the EditText.

Comment: I know you haven't added any background, I'm not saying that. but a background appears behind the edittext, I think it is related to a margin or something. because even when I set the background to transparent it is still showing a background behind it

Comment: @SSS What do you want the background to look like?

Comment: can you please see the image provided with my question? this is how I want it I want the chats to appear through the background of the edittext while scrolling up.

Comment: @SSS Ah I see. I thought it was how you don't want to get it.

Comment: @SSS Then we can just use a RelativeLayout instead of Linear and align the editText layout to bottom. I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain well from the beginning. yes now I can see through the background while scrolling the messages up, which is what I wanted. However, the last message at the bottom doesn't show because it is hidden behind the edittext. How can I make it scrolls a little more so that all messages are visible?

Comment: @SSS I would recommend to add a transparent footer to the recyclerview with the height of the edittext. That way you can always scroll up and the footer stays behind the edittext.

Comment: ok, I will try that, but is it possible to add a footer to the recycleview? thank you I will search for a way to achieve this

Comment: @SSS I did it myself multiple times. Please consider to accept and upvote this answer, if it was helpful.